# NoSuchElementException not caught

Tags: java, selenium, exception, intellij-idea, automation

I am debugging a test in Java Selenium and created a try and catch to capture a NoSuchElementException error. In Evaluate expression I see that this is indeed the error but in practice the software continues 'finally' and does not do what is written in 'try' and not in 'catch'.
Do you know why?

```
try {
        WebElement cell = table.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td["+returnColumnText+"]"));
        exeptedText = cell.getText();
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("You are trying to access a non-existent cell. Check the values you entered.");
    }
```

Comment: Please post complete, reproducible code. Also, in this case, a complete error description (including stack trace if available) is desirable as well as the page URL if the page is public. If not, an extract of the DOM might suffice. There could be plenty of reasons why this occurring, including that the web element actually exists. We can't tell because we don't have access to any of that information.

Comment: Make sure you have imported `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
` and not `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh I am sure that's not the case. Otherwise, OP would be complaining the code will not compile. In this case, the OP is implying the code runs AND skips over the catch block.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `exeptedText = cell.getText();`, debug your code and examine the `cell` properties. You propably find out the element is there with location 0,0 or with attribute `hidden=true` or simething like that. Consider even possibility there are more `cell` elements by the same locator.

Answer (score 1):

Full name of the exception you want to catch is org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException. Java, however, tries to catch an java.util.NoSuchElementException as a default.

Yes, you should declare full name of the Exception as following snippet.

```
try {
        WebElement cell = table.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td["+returnColumnText+"]"));
        exeptedText = cell.getText();
    }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("You are trying to access a non-existent cell. Check the values you entered.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the full name of the exception and the exception was caught.